# Flutter bloc changing states will remove other properties

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, state, bloc

I have a form that has a header which a user can select a photo from gallery as well as an avatar with the same functionality. Then below that I have a username field which will trigger the TextfieldChange event every time the user writes and it will be emitting the FormError state if the field has errors If the username is valid it will emit the UsernameLoading to search in the database if that username exists. The name also will trigger the TextFieldChange on the onChange to validate if is a correct name and if not it will emit the Error state. and for the About field, every time the user writes, it will subtract the text length from 140. The submit button will be disabled until the form is valid and for the form to be valid it will need a valid username and name.

[image]

The problem I have is that I have the following states:

1. FormInitial
2. FormError // Any errors on fields
   a. errors
3. FormAvatarLoading // User selects image to upload
4. FormAvatarUploadedSuccess // Avatar uploaded successfully
5. FormHeaderLoading // User selects image to upload
6. FormHeaderUploadedSuccess  // Header uploaded successfully
7. FormIsValid // When every field is correct
8. UsernameLoading // When db call to verify username exists

And the events are

1. TextFieldChange
2. SubmitForm
3. ImageChange
4. ImageRemove

For example if the user writes on username and it shows an error, the ErrorState will be emitted, but If I then upload an avatar image, the AvatarSuccess state will be emitted and I will loose my errors. Also if the username is valid and I emit the UsernameLoading to verify the database I will also loose the error in name if it was already shown.

I've tried separating the fields and images in a different bloc, but I don't want to add so many listeners to see if every field is valid. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

When using global `state` make sure that you pass props in ever `emit` and with that update your global `state`

This way emitting won't empty the `state`